# Run multiple laravel-echo-server instance on Local

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-echo, laravel-6.2

I setup multiple projects on local which uses laravel-echo-server + redis + socket.io. At a time I can run the only single laravel-echo-server instance in local. If I tried to run multiple laravel-echo-server instance then getting below error:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

events.js:170
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::6001
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1258:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1306:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1394:7)
```

How we can run multiple laravel-echo-server instance on local?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change laravel-echo-server's port. By default, laravel-echo-server uses `6001` as the default port. If you need running multiple laravel-echo-server instances on your local machine then change the server port.

For example

Set first instance port `6001` then second instance port `6002`

```js
const server = require('laravel-echo-server');

server.run({
    port: 6002
});
```

If `6002` are already used by another service on your machine feel free to change it.

Comment: I want to run all project's laravel-echo-server on 6001. Is that possible? All projects are running by creating virtual host.